# clang 32bit with address sanitizer with nix

Tags: c, clang, 32-bit, nix, address-sanitizer

I'm building an reproducible build environment with nix.
The code is built with clang-10 in 32bit mode.
Moreover it's linked with ASAN.

`clang a.c -m32 -fsanitize=leak`

I'm using the **pkgsi686Linux.clang_10** package in shell.nix

That's the error I'm getting:

> /nix/store/4c4fy3hs558qm0ykif24f200d8mvcrkb-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ld:
> cannot find
> /nix/store/h4h6h98m32xcp18vcbd2mx5rfd34bmw1-clang-wrapper-10.0.1/resource-root/lib/linux/libclang_rt.lsan-i386.a: No such file or directory clang-10: error: linker command failed with
> exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can't seem to find a nix package with **libclang_rt.lsan-i386.a**.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Which files, if any, _do_ exist matching `/nix/store/h4h6h98m32xcp18vcbd2mx5rfd34bmw1-clang-wrapper-10.0.1/resource-root/lib/*/*`?

Comment: only libclang_rt.builtins-i686.a

Comment: I don't know much about clang, but if anyone finds a fix, let's add it to `clang.passthru.tests` in Nixpkgs to avoid breaking it in the future.

Comment: With `clang_14` I can make it compile (I don't even need the `-m32`, `pkgsi686` is enough to build a 32bits binary. Now I'm not sure why but when I run the program it never detects any leakage… but maybe I just don't know how to use the sanitizer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you insist on using clang 10? With a more recent clang everything works as expected; for the tests, just disable optimization with `-O0` or the leakages won't appear (tested with 12, 13 and 14, with clang 11 when I run the binary I get some errors `==517055==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0x0 (0) bytes of SetAlternateSignalStack (error code: 22)`).

For the demonstration, I created a flake [here](https://gist.github.com/tobiasBora/0952c923d3cd892e41fbc3ef025ac020).

```
$ nix build 'git+https://gist.github.com/tobiasBora/0952c923d3cd892e41fbc3ef025ac020?ref=main#hello'

$ file ./result/bin/a.out
./result/bin/a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /nix/store/4nlgxhb09sdr51nc9hdm8az5b08vzkgx-glibc-2.35-163/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped

$ ./result/bin/a.out
Hello world

=================================================================
==548464==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x40c4f2  (/nix/store/3i0ipj0zwpjm8g1fslvfjb5dng4bd9s0--/bin/a.out+0x40c4f2)
    #1 0x43b858  (/nix/store/3i0ipj0zwpjm8g1fslvfjb5dng4bd9s0--/bin/a.out+0x43b858)
    #2 0x7f381db5624d  (/nix/store/4nlgxhb09sdr51nc9hdm8az5b08vzkgx-glibc-2.35-163/lib/libc.so.6+0x2924d) (BuildId: 2bb226bc600b443958c7566207d0d02f8345e6ea)

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).

$ nix build 'git+https://gist.github.com/tobiasBora/0952c923d3cd892e41fbc3ef025ac020?ref=main#hello-32'

$ file ./result/bin/a.out
./result/bin/a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /nix/store/bzw74a7dla8iqk2h8wshwi03fbgj2c5h-glibc-2.35-163/lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped

$ ./result/bin/a.out

Hello world

=================================================================
==554039==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x8055779  (/nix/store/yh4klla6n8c9flgcxd7r05zj705kycdl--/bin/a.out+0x8055779)
    #1 0x8094238  (/nix/store/yh4klla6n8c9flgcxd7r05zj705kycdl--/bin/a.out+0x8094238)
    #2 0xf7c102f9  (/nix/store/bzw74a7dla8iqk2h8wshwi03fbgj2c5h-glibc-2.35-163/lib/libc.so.6+0x212f9) (BuildId: 0fc69f6f66391d65b1e33788a951319bda8ba1d4)

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```